# Had looked or was looking?

Tags: grammar

> **I found my key when I (had looked/ was looking) for something else.**

What is the correct choice and why?

My answer is "**was looking**" because the event of “*founding the key*” was interrupted “*looking for something else*”.

But my teacher says that it’s “**had looked**” but I can’t get convinced.

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't want to be taught by a teacher who says that "**had looked**" is correct here.

Comment: *had looked* would be permissible if the sentence read: *I found me key AFTER I had looked for something else*, making clear that you had finished looking for something else before you found the key.

Answer (score 1):

"**was looking**" is the correct answer. Simply due to the presence of the conjunction **When** which in your example grammatically expects a past tense rather than a past perfect tense.

The only situation when **had looked** would be correct:

- I found my key after I had looked for something else.

OR

- After I had looked for something else I found my key.

> Note that the conjunction "After" is followed by a past perfect tense.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to express what your teacher is talking about, the right way to say it is:

> I found my key *while* I was looking for something else.

This isn't really incorrect:

> I found my key *while* I had looked for something else.

The speaker here is saying that first he/she looked for something else, then stopped looking for that something else (gave up on it or found), but she did end up finding the key.

> I found my key when i (had looked - was looking ) for something else.

The use of *when* is a bit weird.

By using *when*, you are saying that at the time the act of looking was in progress (was happening), or that the act of looking had completed (had happened), you found your key - but *When* also makes the two things it connects a bit disconnected or disjointed - implying it that the two are not strictly dependent on each other - i.e. maybe you *accidentally* found your key.

Comment: I simply cannot agree that "I found my key while I had looked for something else" is anywhere close to idiomatic. The past perfect involves a specific instant of past time. "While" relates to a duration of time. I shall change my down vote if an example of this usage from a competent writer can be cited.